# Prohibit search engines before going live

Tags: search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, search

I want to prohibit search engines to index my web site before going live with it.
If I simple do a `robots.txt` with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Would that cause any issues later when I decide to release it for public exposure?
(I would of course edit it to allow access before doing so)

Answer (score 2):

No, no problem.

As soon as you change it to allow access, well behaved robots such as googlebot will crawl your site again.

(Bad bots will of course ignore at all times.)